# How to interact with confirm dialog in atom package spec?

Tags: coffeescript, tdd, jasmine, jasmine-node, atom-editor

#### Question

What options do I have to write specs for code that involves interacting with an atom editor confirmation dialog?

#### Background

I'm working on a package for atom, and have a command to delete a file that then pushes changes to the server. I'd like to write a test to validate the behavior of the command, but am having trouble coming up with a good way to simulate clicking the cancel/okay button on the confirmation dialog

The command code looks like this

```
atom.workspaceView.command "mavensmate:delete-file-from-server", =>
  # do setup stuff (build the params object)
  atom.confirm
    message: "You sure?"
    buttons:
      Cancel: => # nothing to do here, just let the window close
      Delete: => # run the delete handler
        @mm.run(params).then (result) =>
          @mmResponseHandler(params, result)
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get the cancel or delete callbacks to run in a spec. I've been digging through all the atom specs and scouring google, but nothing seems to come up. I'd hoped that setting the return to the index of the callback I want to fire would work, but my delete button callback is never getting called.

```
# Delete the metadata in the active pane from the server
describe 'Delete File from Server', ->
  filePath = ''

  beforeEach ->
    # set up the workspace with a fake apex class
    directory = temp.mkdirSync()
    atom.project.setPath(directory)
    filePath = path.join(directory, 'MyClass.cls')
    spyOn(mm, 'run').andCallThrough()

    waitsForPromise ->
      atom.workspace.open(filePath)

  it 'should invoke mavensmate:delete-file-from-server if confirmed', ->
    spyOn(atom, 'confirm').andReturn(1)
    atom.workspaceView.trigger 'mavensmate:delete-file-from-server'
    expect(mm.run).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Is there a better way to mimic the user clicking a button on the confirmation dialog? Are there any workarounds to getting this tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a good way to simulate interaction with a confirmation dialog if you're passing in callbacks with your buttons, but if you just pass an array, and have the command trigger respond to that, then you can write a spec as desired.

The command code would then look like this

```
atom.workspaceView.command "mavensmate:delete-file-from-server", =>
  # do setup stuff (build the params object)
  atom.confirm
    message: "You sure?"
    buttons: ["Cancel", "Delete"]
  if answer == 1
    @mm.run(params).then (result) =>
      @mmResponseHandler(params, result)
```

And the spec would work in it's current version

```
# Delete the metadata in the active pane from the server
describe 'Delete File from Server', ->
  filePath = ''

  beforeEach ->
    # set up the workspace with a fake apex class
    directory = temp.mkdirSync()
    atom.project.setPath(directory)
    filePath = path.join(directory, 'MyClass.cls')
    spyOn(mm, 'run').andCallThrough()

    waitsForPromise ->
      atom.workspace.open(filePath)

  it 'should invoke mavensmate:delete-file-from-server if confirmed', ->
    spyOn(atom, 'confirm').andReturn(1)
    atom.workspaceView.trigger 'mavensmate:delete-file-from-server'
    expect(mm.run).toHaveBeenCalled()
```